# Remove item of record without knowing all item

Tags: elm

I have this simulation:

```
 init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
    init = ({ dog = List Dog }, Cmd.none)

    type alias Dog =
      { name : String
      , age : Int
      , price : Float
      , extra = List Extra
      }

    type alias Extra =
      { allergies : List String
      , wishes : List String
      }


    [{ name = "Hot"
     , age = 1
     , price = 300.5
     , extra = [{...}]
     },
     { name = "Dog"
     , age = 3
     , price = 150.0
     , extra = [{...}]
    }]
```

And I want to remove only 'extras' of Dog, in determined part of the code:

```
[{ name = "Hot"
 , age = 1
 , price = 300.5
 },
 { name = "Dog"
 , age = 3
 , price = 150.0
}]
```

I can do this by mapping the entire list and generating a new one by removing 'extra' occurrence:

```
removeExtraOfDogs dogList =  
     (dogList |> List.map (\dog ->
          { name = dog.name
          , age = dog.age
          , price = dog.price
          }
        ))
```

but I want to make it dynamic to just pass the extra to remove, without having to know what variables there are in the type and recreate it

Comment: why are you trying to remove a field? Why not just make a new type alias with ` { name, age, price }`?

Comment: @naomik, because in the project I'm developing, it has +50 types in which I need to do the same thing as taking 1 or 2 items of record. Reason: I need to export in .csv format and I do not want 'extra' to go along.

Comment: I’d recommend you read up on Json encoding/decoding in Elm. The same rules will apply for encoding Csv - I only say read about Json becuase you’re likely to find more applicable search results

Comment: I understand your answer. However, between the work of creating Json and performing this archaic work. Sorry, I prefer the archaic way.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elm used to have this feature but [it was removed a while ago](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/985). But, based on your use case described in a comment, I don't think you need this feature. You can instead use extensible record feature of Elm to allow passing different records into a function as long as they contain a fixed set of fields.

For example, let's say you have two types with `name` and `age` fields and having an extra incompatible field:

```
type alias Foo = { name : String, age : Int, extra : List String }
type alias Bar = { name : String, age : Int, extra : Int }
```

You can define a function that takes a record with a `name` field of type `String` and `age` of type `Int` and any extra fields:

```
encode : { r | name : String, age : Int } -> String
encode record = record.name ++ "," ++ toString record.age
```

You'll can now pass both `Foo` and `Bar` to this function because they both satisfy the requirements of the type signature.

Comment: For performance reasons I will be in archaic mode (because I only need to use this once per type on every system)